# Javascript .Length()

Tags: javascript, methods

Having an issue with .Length() - not sure where I am going wrong?

```
        function isFieldGreaterThanMinimumLength(input, minimumValue)
        {
            if(document.frmRegister[input].value.length() < minimumValue)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

I call the above method using `isFieldGreaterThanMinimumLength("csUsername",5)`.

Comment: Whats is the issue? Please explain your issue.

Answer (score 5):

Use .length not .length()

```
    function isFieldGreaterThanMinimumLength(input, minimumValue)
    {
        if(document.frmRegister[input].value.length < minimumValue)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having,

```
         if(document.frmRegister[input].value.length() < minimumValue)
```

Try below one,

```
         if(document.frmRegister[input].value.length < minimumValue)
```

hope it helps...